# How to specify amplitude threshold in a filter in MatLab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, matlab-figure

Hi i wanted to get some clarification on how to specify a amplitude threshold on an ellip filter.

This is what I have done so far

```
fmin  = 20;  % minimum passband frequency in Hz (High Gamma)
fmax  = 30;  % maximum passband frequency in Hz (High Gamma)
Rs    = 20; % stopband attenuation in dB
Rp    = 1;  % passband ripples in dB



% for High gamma band 
[order, Wn] = ellipord([fmin/(fs/2), fmax/(fs/2)], [(fmin-1)/(fs/2), (fmax+1)/(fs/2)], Rp, Rs);
[B,A] = ellip(order, Rp, Rs, [fmin/(fs/2), fmax/(fs/2)]);
```

I am new to this but is it correct for me to assume that Rs and Rp are the amplitude thresholds, which will be allowed through? Or do I have do something else. Currently after averaging out the data to remove common noise and using ranksum to get the energy data, my plot looks like the image.

[image]

As you can see there is a massive spike and I would like to reduce the threshold so spikes like that can be ignore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rp` and `Rs` represent the passband ripple and stopband attenuation in the frequency domain respectively. Plotting the frequency response of your filter with `freqz(B,A)` would give you a plot which looks like:

[image: Frequency response]

As you can see the response in the passband between your specified `fmin` (20Hz) and `fmax` (30Hz) varies a little. This variation is the passband ripple `Rp`.

Outside the passband (below 20Hz and above 30Hz), the response varies but would not exceed -20dB. This is the stopband attenuation `Rs`.

So, those parameters do not represent threshold time-domain amplitude, although you may be able to reduce a little the overall amplitude of large impulses by increasing the stopband attenuation `Rs`. Note however that a better improvement of your signal would generally need to take into account the input as well as the desired output characteristics.